# WooCommerce custom Ajax add to cart: How to set a custom price?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to add a product from an on_click event at checkout.
That product's price is calculated dynamically with an external API so it is registered as having a price of 0 in woocommerce itself. I am trying to add this product to the cart (working) and then set that product's price to the one I receive from the API (not working). Here is the relevant code:

AJAX call on click:

```
       jQuery('#theftdaminsurance').on('click', function(){
        jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
        data: {
            action: 'add_product_to_cart_checkout',
            // add your parameters here
            price: <?php echo $year_dam_price; ?>,
            productid: ins_product_id
        },
        success: function (output) {
        document.getElementById("loaderdiv").style.display = "none";
        jQuery(document.body).trigger("update_checkout");
        }
        });
        });
```

I checked everything here and the call is made properly with all the right info being passed on.
Here is the function being called:

```
add_action('wp_ajax_add_product_to_cart_checkout', 'add_product_to_cart_checkout');

// register the ajax action for unauthenticated users
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_add_product_to_cart_checkout', 'add_product_to_cart_checkout');

function add_product_to_cart_checkout() {
    $product_id = $_REQUEST['productid'];
    $price = floatval($_REQUEST['price']);
    $ebike_ids = array(17386,17385,17382,17378,17375,17372,17370,17369,17364,16132,16130,4561,4550,3490,2376);
    $found = false;
    //check if there is something in cart
    if ( sizeof( WC()->cart->get_cart() ) > 0 ) {
        //Delete all preexisting insurance products and find qty of ebikes
        foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {
            $product_idebike = $cart_item['product_id'];
            if ( ($cart_item['product_id'] == "16600") || ($cart_item['product_id'] == "16653") || ($cart_item['product_id'] == "16654") || ($cart_item['product_id'] == "16655") ||($cart_item['product_id'] == "16659") || ($cart_item['product_id'] == "16660")) {
                        WC()->cart->remove_cart_item( $cart_item_key );
            }           
        //get ebike quantity
    for ($x = 0; $x <= 14; $x++) {
        if ($product_idebike == $ebike_ids[$x]) {
            $quantity =  $cart_item['quantity'];
            break;
        }
    }
        }
            // if command is not to remove add relevant products
                if ($price != "-1") {
                WC()->cart->add_to_cart( $product_id, $quantity );
                foreach( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ){
                    $id = $cart_item['product_id'];
                    if ($product_id == $id) {
                        $cart_item['data']->set_price( $price );
                    }
                }
                }
            
    }

}
```

Here I basically debugged everythingcarefully and everything behaves as it should but the set_price function. I cannot get it to update the product's price to the one passed in the AJAX call. The price remains 0 once the checkout is updated and before it is as well. Am i calling or using this function the wrong way?

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: I realised that if I use something as simple as that:
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'set_insurance_price' );
 
function set_insurance_price( $cart_object ) {
 foreach ( $cart_object->get_cart() as $hash => $value ) {
  $value['data']->set_price( 10 );
 }
}
The price is switched to 10 so is there a way to adapt that to an AJAX call?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that you are making things much more complicated than they should be on your Ajax receiver function…

Note that you can add custom cart item data when using `WC_Cart` `add_to_cart()` method, so you will add your insurance price as custom cart item data and afterwards use it to set the price.

Here is your revisited Ajax PHP receiver function:

```
add_action('wp_ajax_add_product_to_cart_checkout', 'add_product_to_cart_checkout');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_add_product_to_cart_checkout', 'add_product_to_cart_checkout');
function add_product_to_cart_checkout() {
    if ( isset($_POST['productid']) && isset($_POST['price']) && ! WC()->cart->is_empty() ) {
        $product_id     = intval($_POST['productid']);
        $price          = floatval($_POST['price']);
        $ebike_ids      = array(17386,17385,17382,17378,17375,17372,17370,17369,17364,16132,16130,4561,4550,3490,2376);
        $insurance_ids  = array(16600,16653,16654,16655,16659,16660);
        $found          = false;
        $ebike_quantity = 0;

        // Loop through cart items
        foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {
            // Delete all preexisting insurance products
            if ( in_array( $cart_item['product_id'],  $insurance_ids ) ) {
                WC()->cart->remove_cart_item( $cart_item_key );
            }

            // Get ebikes total quantity
            if ( in_array( $cart_item['product_id'],  $ebike_ids ) ) {
                $ebike_quantity +=  $cart_item['quantity'];
            }
        }

        // If command is not to remove add insurance product with price as custom cart item data
        if ( $price >= 0 && $cart_item['insurance_price'] > 0 ) {
            WC()->cart->add_to_cart( $product_id, $ebike_quantity, 0, array(), array( 'insurance_price' => $price ) );
        }
        die();
    }
}
```

Then to set the price you will use:

```
// Set insurance price from custom cart item data
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'set_insurance_price' );
function set_insurance_price( $cart ) {
    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
       return;

    foreach ( $cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {
        if( isset($cart_item['insurance_price']) && $cart_item['insurance_price'] > 0 ) {
            $cart_item['data']->set_price( $cart_item['insurance_price'] );
        }
    }
}
```

Now It should works.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this! It works well!, i just removed isset($_POST['productid']) as I dont pass it for the remove request and also could you explain why you added: "&& $cart_item['insurance_price'] > 0 )" in the add product section as because this is not defined it prevents from adding the product.
Thanks again for your help!